# How to declare many character arrays in C

Tags: arrays, declare

I want to declare two character arrays in C. the first array is good, but, there is nothing at the second. I can't print anything even T[0] while my input is not empty. How can I declare them? Thanks for your help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char S[50],T[50]; 
    scanf("%s",S); fflush(stdin); scanf("%s",T); 
    for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
    {
        printf("%c", (*strchr(T,ch)) );
    }
}
```

I have used *fflush(stdin)* but nothing happens, I want to print different characters appearing in the second array in alphabet order

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault is because `strchr(T,ch)` returns `NULL` whenever the value is not found.

It's basically doing this:

```
char *c = NULL;
printf("%c", *c); // segmentation fault!
```

So you need to guard against it, with something like this:

```
char *c = strchr(T,ch);
if (c != NULL) {
    printf("%c", *c);
}
```

inside the for loop.